# Initializing variables in bash

Tags: unix, terminal, environment

I'm migrating windows CMD script to bin/bash on unix.
The goal of initial script was to setting up some variables, so after anything run from this cmd window was using that variables.
How can I do same in UNIX? Looks like simple

```
MyVar="value"
```

doesn't work. It visible only in script itself, not from terminal where it was run.

Comment: Why do you think that it doesn't work?

Comment: You cannot modify the parent environment. Source the script instead of running it if you want to set some variables in the *current* session.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can initialize shell variables with simple assignments

```
$ foo="fooval"
$ echo $foo
  fooval
```

These variables won't spread to unrelated child processes:

```
$ foo=fooval
$ sh -c 'printf "\"%s\"" $foo' 
  ""
```

To make them spread, you need to export them into the process's (shell's)
environment (make them into "environment variables" (these are commonly capitalized, i.e.,
`FOO` instead of `foo`)

```
$ export foo
$ sh -c 'echo $foo' 
  fooval
```

You can assign and export in one step:

```
$ export foo=fooval
```

Environment variables will never spread anywhere but down the process hierarchy.
(Only to children, never to parents or completely unrelated processes)
Therefore, if you have a script with variable assignments, you need to source it, not execute it:

```
 $ ./envvars #won't affect the parent shell
 $ . ./envvars #this will
```

There are no per-terminal variables (though there are per-terminal configurations with fixed keys accessible manipulatable with the `stty` tool).

Answer (score 1):

Create a file test.sh

add the following line:

```
export b="key"
```

Now goto the terminal and do the following :

```
source ./test.sh
echo $b
```

Output:

```
key
```